# GridView sorting with combine column not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have the Table employee with two column FirstName and LastName, I do not like to combine it by query, then when populating to GridView I use :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Name">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblEmpName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") + " " + Eval("FirstName") + "" %>' SortExpression="LastName,FirstName" />

                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Some code behind that work fine in the other pages:

```
private SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
                {
                    ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
                }
                return (SortDirection) ViewState["sortDirection"];
            }
            set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }
        }

        public string SortField
        {
            get
            {
                var o = ViewState["SortExpression"];
                if (o == null)
                {
                    return "EmpCode";
                }
                return Convert.ToString(o);
            }

            set { ViewState["SortExpression"] = value; }
        }
private const string ASCENDING = " ASC";
        private const string DESCENDING = " DESC";
 private void AddSortDirectionImage(int columnIndex, GridViewRow headerRow)
        {
            Image sortImage = new Image();
            if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                sortImage.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/Admin/img/sortascending.gif";
                sortImage.AlternateText = "Ascending Order";
            }
            else
            {
                sortImage.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/Admin/img/sortdescending.gif";
                sortImage.AlternateText = "Descending Order";
            }
            headerRow.Cells[columnIndex].Controls.Add(sortImage);
        }

        private int GetSortColumnIndex()
        {
            var SortExpression = "";
            foreach (DataControlField field in grvEmployeeRecords.Columns)
            {
                if (ViewState["SortExpression"] != null)
                {
                    if (field.SortExpression == (string) ViewState["SortExpression"])
                    {
                        return grvEmployeeRecords.Columns.IndexOf(field);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    SortExpression = "EmpCode";
                    if (field.SortExpression == SortExpression)
                    {
                        return grvEmployeeRecords.Columns.IndexOf(field);
                    }
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
 protected void grvEmployeeRecords_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            var sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

            if (e.SortExpression == "FirstName ASC, LastName ASC")
                e.SortExpression = "FirstName DESC, LastName DESC";
            else if (e.SortExpression == "FirstName DESC, LastName DESC")
                e.SortExpression = "FirstName ASC, LastName ASC";
            ViewState["SortExpression"] = sortExpression;
            if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
                BindGrid(sortExpression);
            }
            else
            {
                GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
                BindGrid(sortExpression);
            }
        }

        protected void grvEmployeeRecords_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header))
            {
                var sortColumnIndex = GetSortColumnIndex();
                if (sortColumnIndex != -1)
                {
                    AddSortDirectionImage(sortColumnIndex, e.Row);
                }
                //Add Css for Header
                foreach (Control ctl in e.Row.Controls)
                {
                    foreach (Control ctl2 in ctl.Controls)
                    {
                        if (ReferenceEquals(ctl2.GetType().BaseType, typeof (LinkButton)))
                        {
                            ((LinkButton) ctl2).CssClass = "OrderBy";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

private void BindGrid(string SortExpression)
        {
            var objBind = new DataTable();

            if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
            {
                objBind = BindData(SortExpression, ASCENDING);

            }
            else
            {
                objBind = BindData(SortExpression, DESCENDING);
            }

            if ((objBind != null))
            {
                if (objBind.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    grvEmployeeRecords.DataSource = objBind;
                    grvEmployeeRecords.DataBind();
                    trMessage.Visible = false;
                    grvEmployeeRecords.Visible = true;

                    updatePanel.Update();
                }
                else
                {
                    trMessage.Visible = true;
                    grvEmployeeRecords.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private DataTable BindData(string SortExpression, string SortType)
        {
            var dt = EmployeeService.Employee_GetByKeyword(txtSearch.Text, SortExpression, SortType);
            return dt;
        }
```

And the Store procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Employee_GetByKeyword]
    @Keyword nvarchar(250),
    @SortField nvarchar(50),
    @SortType nvarchar(10)
AS
    declare @strSQL   nvarchar(1000)
    declare @strWhere nvarchar(500)
    declare @strOrder nvarchar (50)

    set @strSQL= 'Select * from Employee'
    set @strWhere =' Where 1=1 '

    if @Keyword<>''
        set @strWhere= @strWhere  +' And (EmpCode like N''%' +@Keyword+'%'' 
            Or LastName like N''%' +@Keyword+'%'' Or FirstName like N''%' +@Keyword+'%'' 
            Or EmpMobile like N''%' +@Keyword+'%'' Or EmpIDCard like N''%' +@Keyword+'%'' 
            Or TempAddress like N''%' +@Keyword+'%'' Or PIT_No like N''%' +@Keyword+'%''
            Or ContractNo like N''%' +@Keyword+'%'' Or ATMAccount like N''%' +@Keyword+'%''
            Or EmpEmail like N''%' +@Keyword+'%'' Or PermanentAddress like N''%' +@Keyword+'%'')'

    if @SortField=''
    Begin
        set @strOrder =' Order by EmpCode'
    End
Else
    Begin
        set @strOrder =' Order by '+ @SortField + ' '+ @SortType
    End

set @strSQL=@strSQL+@strWhere+@strOrder
print @strSQL
exec sp_executesql @strSQL
Go
```

Everything work well, Display data, Search,.... but only the Sort not work!
What is wrong with it? Please help!
[image]

Query results:
[image]

Actual print @strSQL string:

```
declare @Keyword nvarchar(250)
    declare @SortField nvarchar(50)
    declare @SortType nvarchar(10)

    declare @strSQL   nvarchar(1000)
    declare @strWhere nvarchar(500)
    declare @strOrder nvarchar (50)

    set @strSQL= 'Select * from Employee'
    set @strWhere =' Where 1=1 '
    set @Keyword='l';
    set @SortField='FirstName'
    set @SortType='Desc'
```

and the result:

```
 Select * from Employee Where 1=1  And (EmpCode like N'%l%' 
                Or LastName like N'%l%' Or FirstName like N'%l%' 
                Or EmpMobile like N'%l%' Or EmpIDCard like N'%l%' 
                Or TempAddress like N'%l%' Or PIT_No like N'%l%'
                Or ContractNo like N'%l%' Or ATMAccount like N'%l%'
                Or EmpEmail like N'%l%' Or PermanentAddress like N'%l%') Order by FirstName Desc
```

Comment: `ORDER BY LTRIM(RTRIM(FirstName)) COLLATE Latin1_General_bin`

Comment: My problem is the GridView column not work. We cannot click to the column header that contains the SortExpression, So I cannot test if the query Ok or Not, but I tested it in the SQL Server is OK. It works . Please help me find out the GridView column header problem,. I already debug but cannot find any errors.

Comment: By changing : `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName">
                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Highlight(Eval("LastName").ToString()) %>'  />
                                                                
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>`